# Replace values in pandas datatable if in list

Tags: python, pandas

How can I replace values in the datatable `data` with information in `filllist` if a value is in `varlist`?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3, 10]})
varlist = (5,7,9,10)
fillist = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
data[data.isin(varlist)==True] = 'is in varlist!'
```

Returns data as:

```
    A               B
 0  is in varlist!  1
 1  6               2
 2  3               3
 3  4               is in varlist!
```

But I want:

```
    A               B
 0  a               1
 1  6               2
 2  3               3
 3  4               d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `replace` method of the dataframe.

```
replace_map = dict(zip(varlist, fillist))
data.replace(replace_map)
```

this gives

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  6  2
2  3  3
3  4  d
```

The documentation is here in case you want to use it in a different way:
[replace method documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: thanks for your quick response, it works and using the dictionary instead of two lists is much more elegant